# While loop with getline doesn't end for user input

Tags: c++

I thought `getline` stops at a newline character, but the while loop does not end? it returns the correct data but it just sits in the terminal window. For example:

> ```
> Enter an expression: #5+4#5+4
> (blinking cursor)
> ```

(can enter data forever and press enter forever and it wont exit)

my code, (main.cpp):

```
    int main()
    {
    string exp;
        cout << "Enter an Infix Expression:";

        while (getline(cin, exp, '#'))
        {
            string token = exp;
            string post;
            cout << token << endl;
            IntoPost *infix = new IntoPost(token.length());
            post = infix->inToPost(token);
            cout << post << endl;
        }
        cin.get();
    }
```

Comment: How do you see the loop ending? What condition do you believe will make `getline` return something that converts to `false`?

Comment: I thought newline method terminates after it reaches \n?

Comment: I did not ask about whether or not a method terminates, as it must terminate in order to return a value. I asked about the value returned by a method *when* that method terminates.

Comment: Your program is fine it's just that your console is line-delimited which means you have to enter a new line character in order for the program to continue.

Answer (score 1):

### The Solution Using EOF

<strike>Your current program is looping endlessly because `getline` returns `std::basic_istream`, so while(getline()) will never equate to 'false'.</strike>

As @0x499602D2 has stated, your program is working as intended, but the extraction from getline can only end in two ways, as indicated by the reference [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/?kw=getline):

> Extracts characters from is and stores them into str until the delimitation character delim is found (or the newline character, '\n', for when no delimiter is specified).
>
> The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in is or if some other error occurs during the input operation.

The first condition is difficult to pull off, as inputs on console are triggered by the \n character.

As for the second condition, as per @DavidC.Rankin:

> You can also generate a manual EOF on Linux with [Ctrl+d] or windows with [Ctrl+z] (generally twice is required)

This means the *solution is to use [Ctrl+d] or [Ctrl+z]* to trigger the second condition to end your while loop at any time.

---

### Alternative Using a Break Statement

One alternative way you can try to end the loop instead is breaking on input of an 'exit' string:

(1)

```
#include <algorithm>
//...
    while (getline(cin, exp, '#'))
    {
        // removes meaningless endline chars from input
        exp.erase(std::remove(exp.begin(), exp.end(), '\n'), exp.end()); 
        if (exp == "exit"){
            break;
        }
        //... Your While Block Code Here!
    }
```

To break out of your while loop, you can simply use:

> exit#

# Note, the `endls` from your `couts` in the loop will *bleed into your inputs* on your next `while (getline(cin, exp, '#'))`, giving us unwanted newlines. To prevent this, we can get rid of the endlines from the inputs by using std::erase(). If you wish to keep those endlines in your input, simply set `string token = exp;` in front of the erase() line.

Comment: You can also generate a manual `EOF` on Linux with `[Ctrl+d]` or windows with `[Ctrl+z]` (generally twice is required)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin You're absolutely right, I can't believe I completely forgot about doing that. I think your comment itself should be the answer to the question, since it allows the code to resolve without any changes.

Answer (score 0):

That's right, getline blocks the execution of the loop until a line separator is received and returns while that all is well, in the next step everything is repeated. If you want the loop not to be infinite - then put the Boolean variable key in the loop condition, and from the input check if the last character is an exit symbol and if so switch the variable key